How can I find or log inbound traffic connecting to a PostgreSQL database instance?
I have a postgres instance where I need to find out who/what is connecting. The installed version of postgres is 9.0.1. The instance sits on a linux box, SUSE I believe. Where could I look if it is already logging this? If it isn't what could I enable? I need the origin hostname and/or ip, I don't really need any other info outside of that.

You can enable the log_connections parameter.

I'm obliged to tell you that running a 24 years old version of Postgres, or any software for that matter, is not a very wise decision. I'm sure you can offer an excuse, but still.

Err... that'd be 14 years! :-) But yes, you are correct!

Got it, between this answer and this link
